# neo4j edit distance search

Tags: neo4j, cypher, edit-distance

I am running neo4j 3.0.4 and want do a search on the node property using edit distance of 1. I searched the documentation and couldn't find anything, the closest I found was regex search. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a manual Lucene index, e.g. via the APOC procedure library.

Installation of the library, see: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures

Documentation: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_full_text_search

```
CALL apoc.index.search("locations", "Address.address:Paris~") YIELD node AS addr
MATCH (addr)<-[:HAS_ADDRESS]-(company:Company)
RETURN company LIMIT 50
```

Comment: This works perfectly, just one step in the installation was missing:
I had to manually add this line to the .neo4j.conf file:

`dbms.directories.plugins=/Applications/Neo4j\ Community\ Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins`

Comment: Keep in mind that the full index search returns only the top 100 results, so if the set of nodes you're searching over is above 100, you may not find the expected result set if you're trying to find specific nodes in a pattern. @MichaelHunger Do you know of any way to mitigate this problem?